# Função .blur() não executa com elemento adicionado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, cep

Possuo um select que ao selecionar a opção **Brazil** ele adiciona um `input` para **CEP** e ao selecionar **France** ele adiciona um `input` para **ZIP**. Com o valor desses inputs vou fazer uma consulta a API como exemplo vou utilizar a do `viacep`. Porém o blur não funciona, eu digito o CEP dentro e não ocorre nada, tentei dar um alert() para ver se ele estava executando mas não esta.

**Código que gera os campos:**

```
$('#user_country').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'Brazil') {
        if (!$('#user_cep').length) {
            $('#user_zip').remove();
            let input_cep = '<input type="text" placeholder="CEP" name="user_cep" id="user_cep" maxlength="8">';
            $('#user_country').after(input_cep);
        }
    } else if (this.value == 'France') {
        if (!$('#user_zip').length) {
            $('#user_cep').remove();
            let input_zip = '<input type="text" placeholder="ZIP" name="user_zip" id="user_zip" maxlength="5"/>';
            $('#user_country').after(input_zip);
        }
    } else {
        $('#user_cep').remove();
        $('#user_zip').remove();
    }
});
```

Essa parte está OK, esta adicionando os campos na tela corretamente, porém na hora de consultar não esta funcionando.

**Teste com o VIACEP que não funciona, não executa nada**

```
    $('#user_cep').blur(function () {
    let cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (cep != "") {
        let validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
        if (validacep.test(cep)) {
            $("#user_city").val("...");
            $("#user_state").val("...");
            $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/?callback=?", function (dados) {
                if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                    $("#user_city").val(dados.localidade);
                    $("#user_state").val(dados.uf);
                }
                else {
                    alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    }
});
```

Ele simplesmente não entra nessa função.

Comment: Olá Guilherme! Veja se resolve. Seria: `$(document).on('blur', '#user_cep', function () {`

Comment: No meu caso ficaria assim. `$(document).on("blur", '#user_cep', function () {` ???

Comment: Agora executou. Não fez a consulta na API mas pelo menos já entrou na função.

Comment: O caminho é esse. Abs! ;)